# Can PySpark write array of strings to a database through a JDBC driver?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cratedb

I am working with PySpark and I want to insert an array of strings into my database that has a JDBC driver but I am getting the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
```

This error happens when I have an ArrayType(StringType()) format for a UDF. And when I try to overwrite the column type:

```
.option("createTableColumnTypes", "col1 ARRAY, col2 ARRAY, col3 ARRAY, col4 ARRAY")
```

I get:

```
DataType array is not supported.(line 1, pos 18)
```

This makes me wonder if the problem is within Spark 3.1.2 where there is no mapping for array and I have to convert it into a string or is it coming from the driver that I am using?

For reference, I am using [CrateDB](https://crate.io/) as database. And here is its driver: [crate.io/docs/jdbc/en/latest](http://crate.io/docs/jdbc/en/latest)

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: Just updated the question referencing the driver

Answer (score 2):

Probably switching to use [Postgres JDBC](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) with CrateDB instead of `crate-jdbc` could solve your issue.

Sample PySpark program tested with CrateCB 4.6.1 and postgresql 42.2.23:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a = [1, 2]),
    Row(a = [3, 4])
])
df

df.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://<url-to-server>:5432/?sslmode=require") \
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
  .option("dbtable", "<tableName>") \
  .option("user", "<username>") \
  .option("password", "<password>") \
  .save()
```

Comment: That worked. Now I am getting some other errors:

While inserting the arrays I get only the first 1,000 rows from 1,000,000 and it throws: 
`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o536.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (844a50665e58 executor driver): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: line 1:1: mismatched input 'ROLLBACK' expecting {'SELECT', 'DEALLOCATE', 'CREATE', 'ALTER', 'KILL', 'BEGIN'...`

Comment: And when I try to insert float numbers defined in spark udf:
`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1014.save.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Cannot find data type: float4`

Comment: For some reason the first problem is able to be resolved after defining a batchsize option that matches the dataframe's rows. Now all the rows are inserted

Comment: The Spark `PostgresDialect` maps float and double to `FLOAT4` and `FLOAT8` respectively ([src](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/PostgresDialect.scala#L88-L89)) which isn't supported by CrateDB right now. Don't know if there is a workaround for this unfortunately

Comment: Just tried the 'createTableColumnTypes' option and it worked by defining it as float in it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool that it works. FYI: next version of CrateDB will include FLOAT4 / FLOAT8 and should work out of the box. [PR](https://github.com/crate/crate/pull/11634) for this was just merged

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe try adding the datatype for the array i.e. `ARRAY(TEXT)` ?

```
.option("createTableColumnTypes", "col1 ARRAY(TEXT), col2 ARRAY(TEXT), col3 ARRAY(TEXT), col4 ARRAY(TEXT)")
```

```sql
SELECT ['Hello']::ARRAY;
--> SQLParseException[line 1:25: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT ['Hello']::ARRAY limit']
```

```sql
SELECT ['Hello']::ARRAY(TEXT);
--> SELECT OK, 1 record returned (0.002 seconds)
```

Comment: With that I get: 

`ParseException: 
mismatched input 'TEXT' expecting INTEGER_VALUE(line 1, pos 24)`